# Is there a way to watch different v-model in the same component?

Tags: vue.js

I dont know how to put this but I have a component that I use in two different places and this component has an `<input v-model="model" >` .
and I am watching this v-model in my component; 
the problem is that model changes; in one place I have model = array.val1 and in the second I have model = array.val2 
and I wanna do somthing when model =  array.val1, and I wanna do some different thing when model  = array.val2 
Its like I wanna do a condition on model if it equal something do this else do  this

this is my component

```
Vue.component('boisson-view', {
props: ["boiss", "model","type","name"],
template: `
    <div class="radio">
        <label> 
        <input :type="type" :name="name" v-model="model" :value="boiss.id" > 
            {{boiss.name}} 
            <img :src="boiss.link" :id="boiss.id" style="display:none;position: fixed;">
        </label>
    </div>`,
created:function(){
    this.setboisson = vm.setboisson;
},
watch: {

    'model': { handler : function(val) {
        // this will get triggered within boisson-view component, when one of your "o" changes
        if(val !== null )
        this.ord.is_menu = true;
        else
        this.ord.is_menu = false;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(val));

        },deep:true
    },

}
```

So I dont wanna do the same thing to that model when ever I reuse the component

Comment: Maybe I will use two components instead of reusing the same one

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the component many times you want, you can handle this with a condition in your watch `model`

```
if(model === array.val1) {
   // do something
}

if(model === array.val2) {
  //do another thing
}
```